# Callback URL matching logic

Tags: c#, .net, http, url, uri

I am working on an OAuth type module. In this i have a collection of URLs which are called as Whitelist URLs. I have to check whether the callback URL specified matches with any of these URLs in the collection.

I've written the following code. Please let me know whether i've done it correctly or am i missing some steps. Also, please let me know if i need any kind of refactoring if i want to unit test these methods.

The code is:

```
public class ValidateURLs
{
    public bool MatchRedirectUrl(string requestUrl, IList<string> urlCollection)
    {
        var requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
        foreach (var url in urlCollection)
        {
            var matchUri = new Uri(url);
            if (IsDomainMatching(requestUri, matchUri))
            {
                if (IsPortMatch(requestUri, matchUri))
                {
                    if (IsPathMatch(requestUri, matchUri))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsDomainMatching(Uri url1, Uri url2)
    {
        var result = String.Compare(url1.Host, url2.Host);
        if (result == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private bool IsPortMatch(Uri url1, Uri url2)
    {
        if (url1.Port == url2.Port)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsPathMatch(Uri url1, Uri url2)
    {
        return (url1.PathAndQuery.StartsWith(url2.PathAndQuery) || url2.PathAndQuery.StartsWith(url1.PathAndQuery));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Suyog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing all this code, you should look at [Uri.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.compare.aspx)

But you also want path.startswith to be part of the comparison.  Notice it takes a bitwise enum UriComponents to define which components of the url to compare.  So you could replace much of the code with Uri.Compare not comparing path and then have a startsWith path ANDed.

So all your code could be replaced with something like:

```
 Uri.Compare(uri1, uri2, UriComponents.HostAndPort, ...) == 0 &&
 (url1.PathAndQueryStartsWith(url2.PathAndQuery) || url.PathAndQueryStartsWith(...));
```

On a side note, code in this form:

```
    var result = String.Compare(url1.Host, url2.Host);
    if (result == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Can simply be written as:

```
return String.Compare(url1.Host, url2.Host) == 0;
```

You should also do case insensitive compares with: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: Uri.Compare will match the exact Url. For e.g. it will return 0 if the url exactly matches. i dont want this. what i want is http://foo.com/a/b should return a match if i compare it with http://foo.com/a or vice-versa

Comment: It takes UriComponents bitwise enum to define which components of the uri to compare:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7767559y.aspx

Comment: So you use Uri.Compare and then a subsequent path compare.  I'll update.

Comment: your logic makes sense. Also, is there anything else i need to do for getting a url match?